# Play Framework - package does not exist

Tags: java, playframework, compilation

When I run:

```
compile
```

from play console I get the following error:

```
[info] Compiling 10 Scala sources and 7 Java sources to C:\Development\play\project\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[error] C:\Development\play\project\app\com\me\project\controllers\Application.java:27: error: package com.me.project.views does not exist
[error]                 return ok(com.me.project.views.html.index(null));
[error]                                              ^
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 23-Mar-2014 19:00:24
```

However if I change that line to `return ok("something")`, then it compiles and I can see that the views folder is generated under:

```
C:\Development\play\project\target\scala-2.10\project\target\scala-2.10\classes_managed\com\me\project\views\html
```

so it looks as though the package should exist, no? I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

**Update 1**

My source templates are located under:

```
com.me.project.views
```

Strange enough, when I can get the source to compile (as I mentioned above) eclipse will give me auto-complete on `com.nat.aegis.views.html` and I can see an `index` class located there too in the auto-complete dialogue. I have tried cleaning, refreshing and recompiling over and over but it is having no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Ok I was porting a Scala project to Java and I noticed the following:

in the Scala project the way to reference a template is the way that I had in the example in the original question, however this is not correct in Java, the line should be:

```
return ok(com.me.project.views.html.index.render(null));
```

The compiler error didn't really allude to this but the response from @avik made me look closer at the docs (my brain is still in Scala mode).

```
[info] Compiling 10 Scala sources and 7 Java sources to C:\Development\play\project\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed 23-Mar-2014 23:39:56
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplates), introducing an HTML template file will lead to Play generating a class in the `views.html` package. The way you organise your templates into packages is then replicated below `views.html` by Play.

As a result, I think your return statement should be as follows:

```
return ok(views.html.com.me.project.index(null));
```

(This admittedly doesn't explain the folder structure you're seeing in your target directory.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this does not seem to fix the issue. Check my **update 1** to see where my source is located, this is the same as a different project that I had using scala (I'm porting across, Scala is too much to learn and develop this project at the same time). In that project though with the same structure I could access the compiled templates using `com.me.project.views.html.index()`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added a folder to the views folder named developer. to this folder I added a tables.scala.html file.

In my controller I would say:

```
public static Result main() {

    return ok(developer.tables.render());
}
```

or

```
public static Result main() {
   return ok(views.developer.tables.render())
}
```

During the run, the compiler said that the "developer package doesn't exists". I usually run clean, reload, and update when adding new views and classes to my project (using eclipse).

After a while, what did the trick was to reference this view like this

```
return ok(views.html.developer.tables.render())
```

Which if you ask me, does not seem very intiutive.

But this works, I hope it works for others as well.